# Programmatically go back to the previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i make `onBackPressed()` go on HomeFragment from every fragment or go to previous fragmant.

Here is the code to set fragment by default Home fragment is open when app starts but on back press app gone close.
need help to solve it out thanks
this is my MainActivityDrawer Class

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver alarm = new GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    alarm.setAlarm(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}
        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_help) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_profile);
            break;
        case 2:

            fragment = new ContactsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_contacts);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new GeoFencFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_geofence);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new HistoryFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_history);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new SettingFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_settimg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}}
```

Comment: You missed line to add fragment transaction into backstack

Comment: thanks can you explain some more about fragment transaction in backstack.

Comment: I think you have line fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); in your original code. Please explain your problem, what you want to achieve. ex you have a home fragment and you can go to fragment 5 fragments from here and on back press you want to come back to home and then on again back press you will exit. for this you do not need to override onBackPress. It will handle by system automatically if you are adding transactions in backstack. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Or you are doing. Fragment home > profile fragment > contact fragment and want to reach home on back press not on profile.

Comment: thanks ,my problem is when i select 2nd or 3rd fragment on these fragment i want on back press button go to homefragment or the privious fragment i have onBackPress in my main Activity drawer but every time i press back button app gone close.

Comment: ok get it adding answer for you problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by doing following:-
1. Do no add fragment transaction in back stack.
2. On back press check if current displaying fragment is not home fragment then show home fragment other wise super.onBackPressd() to close activity.

```
 if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
     else if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame_drawer_layout) != homeFragment)
                {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame_drawer_layout, homeFragment).commit();

                }
                else
                {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
```

Comment: thanks bro i get it , can you explain some more where i add this code in my project. i am new so geting error

Comment: Please add this in onBackPressed() (remove your current code). Please test and let me know this you want to achieve

Comment: homeFragment stores the home fragment. This is class level variable in your drawer activity. Set its value where you are creating home fragment

Comment: thanks in R.id.content_frame_drawer_layout i put container_body but home fragment cannot reslove XML file Name of HomeFragment is fragment_home but its not working

Comment: you are creating fragment = new HomeFragment(); so store this fragment in class level variable Fragment homeFragment. If there is some error we can debug

Comment: no error occur but i am not geting what i want on press back button Activity drawer gome close can you give me you email or some thing where i send you my code

Comment: In OnBackPressed add code in starting :- if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

Comment: By the way this is different question :)

Comment: I replied already. In starting add if block and existing if will be change to else if

Comment: can you provide complete onBackPressed() and MainAcitivityDrawer code i undo all changing becouse no solution

Comment: Sir you have two different questions. Please ask separately.

Comment: By the way just few changes required so no need to replace all code:- store the drawer layout at class level in drawer activity Ex:- mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); ..edited answer for full if/else block

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    remove(this).commit();
```

or use `popBackStackImmediate()`

use `addToBackstack()` before commit().in your activity

when you want to remove the fragment use `popBackStackImmediate()`

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); it will automatically goes to previous fragment when you press back button

Refer to 
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: thanks bro removing fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); is not working in my case when i select 2nd fragment and press back button app  gone close

Answer (score 0):

this code save day first get position value from drawer and store in shared prefrences then get this postion no in onBackPressed thanks Everyone for help

```
 public void onBackPressed()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int fragment_num = sharedPreferences.getInt("pos", 0);
    if(fragment_num != 0)
    {
        displayView(0);
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```